# Weird execution order of chained bluebird .then()s

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Can somebody please explain to me why the following two chained functions:

```
// returns zero if okay
var resetCounter = function (model) {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

model.resetCount(function (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};


// returns the amount of deleted entries
var clearCollection = function (collection) {
  collection.remove({}, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      return Promise.resolve(result);
    }
  });
};

// chaining for demo purposes
var reset = function () {
  return resetCounter(nm)
    .then(console.log('1 -> After newsmodel'))
    .then(resetCounter(sm))
    .then(console.log('2 -> After schoolmodel'))
    .then(resetCounter(um))
    .then(console.log('3 -> After usermodel'))
    .then(clearCollection(nm))
    .then(console.log('4 -> After clearing all news'))
    .then(clearCollection(sm))
    .then(console.log('5 -> After clearing all schools'))
    .then(clearCollection(um))
    .then(console.log('6 -> After clearing all users'))
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

are yielding the following output:

```
1 -> After newsmodel
2 -> After schoolmodel
3 -> After usermodel
4 -> After clearing all news
5 -> After clearing all schools
6 -> After clearing all users
7 -> After inserting news
8 -> After inserting schools
9 -> After inserting users
0
0
0
30
500
100
```

There is an insert function which I'm ommiting in this case. It populates the DB again, after all the stuff has been cleared...

My expected result would have been:

```
0
1 -> After newsmodel
0
2 -> After schoolmodel
0
3 -> After usermodel
500
4 -> After clearing all news
100
5 -> After clearing all schools
30
6 -> After clearing all users
7 -> After inserting news
8 -> After inserting schools
9 -> After inserting users
```

Just to clear it up! In this case I'm not interested in the results of the promise. I am only interested in the execution order of the async operations. That is why I'm not passing any successback or errback to the .then(). I tried to replace "bluebird" with "when" with no success, which clearly tells me that I'm missing something crucial about promises in general. Most examples I came around are using the result of the promise in the following .then(), which again, in this case I'm not interested in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am only interested in the execution order of the async operations. That is why I'm not passing any successback or errback to the .then(). Most examples I came around are using the result of the promise in the following .then(), which again, in this case I'm not interested in.

You don't *have* to use use the result argument, but you always need pass a callback function that the promise can *execute* later.

> I'm missing something crucial about promises in general

A promise does represent the *result* of an operation, not the *operation* itself. That means when you have a promise, the task is already started. You need to use a *function* that can be executed and then returns a promise.

> What am I doing wrong?

The `.then()` method does expect such a function - to be called when the result of the promise (whatever it is) has arrived. The function doesn't need to use that result, but it has to be *callable*.

In your case, you are passing things like:

- `console.log(…)` - which immediately logs the argument and passes `undefined`
- `resetCounter(um))` - which immediately calls the async function and passes the promise to `then`, where it is ignored (as it's not a function)
- `clearCollection(nm)` - which immediately calls the async function, but `clearCollection` does not return anything so we get back `undefined`.

For example,

> ```
> // returns the amount of deleted entries
> var clearCollection = function (collection) {
>   collection.remove({}, …);
> };
> ```

does not actually `return` anything. The only part where you've used `return` is *inside* the callback, where it is meaningless. You will need to construct a `Promise` similar to your `resetCounter` function - or you just use the [Promisification feature](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification):

```
function clearCollection(collection) {
     return Promise.promisify(collection.remove, collection)({});
}
```

Now, your chain should look like this:

```
resetCounter(nm)
.then(function() {
    console.log('1 -> After newsmodel');
    return resetCounter(sm);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('2 -> After schoolmodel');
    return resetCounter(um);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('3 -> After usermodel');
    return clearCollection(nm);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('4 -> After clearing all news');
    return clearCollection(sm);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('5 -> After clearing all schools');
    return clearCollection(um);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('6 -> After clearing all users');
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I do thank you from the depth of my heart sir! You made not only my day, but my recent week(s).

Comment: Just for the sake of argument. Would it have been correct to wrap the "collection.remove({}, ... )" function altogether in a  Promise.resolve() block? I'm asking because I kinda used the "Promise.resolve()"-style and the "return new Promise" style more or less for the same problems... Again, thanks mate.

Comment: No, they're completely different. `Promise.resolve()` immediately takes a value (or a promise) as its argument and gives you a promise for that value. `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {` gives you a promise for the value that you *might* *later* pass to the `resolve` callback.

Comment: I see! Can you enumerate some use cases where you would use a Promise.resolve()? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, whenever you don't know whether you can get a value synchronously or not - you just pass it into `Promise.resolve` and regardless whether its a plain value or a promise, you get back a promise. Also, there are some cases where an abstraction requires you to make a promise from a plain value, for example in the base case of a recursion or so.